# What should be exact Jolt Spec for optionList like following?

Tags: json, jolt

The requirement is to flatten the hierarchical list into single list as shown in output with key's value as KEY and value's value as VALUE in final list. (sample output added).

INPUT:

```
{
    "optionList": [{
        "key": "General",
        "values": [{
            "key": "A",
            "value": ["a"]
        },
        {
            "key": "B",
            "value": ["b"]
        },
        {
            "key": "C",
            "value": ["c"]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Required Output :

```
{
"A":"a",
"B":"b",
"C":"c"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below transformation should work for you:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "optionList": {
        "*": {
          "values": {
            "*": {
              "value": "@(1,key)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

See also:

- [Transpose data in an Array.](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#ritwickgupta)
- [CardinalityTransform](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/CardinalityTransform.java)

Comment: Thanks a ton Michal Ziober.